# 'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: mysql

Please help me.

D:\wamp>cd D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17

D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17>set path=%PATH%;D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17

D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17>mysql -u root -p 
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe is the "bin" subdirectory missing in your path?

```
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have to specify the full path to the MySQL program itself (mysql.exe).

Use

```
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysql.exe -u username -p
```